# Get image paths from RSS feeds

Tags: posts, multisite, rss, blog

I'm displaying the content from one wordpress blog page on my server onto a different wordpress blog on the same server.

Apparently the only way is through RSS feed. 
The images don't show up.

I var_dumped the RSS object and there are no image paths.

How do I get the image paths, or the filename of the image?

Or how do I force the source blog to include the image information in the feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are in the feed, if the feed is a fullfeed, not a excerpt. Check the xml snytax in atom format for `<content:encoded>` or in RSS2 for `<description>`.
In this tags you can find the images of the content.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discovering that using RSS to port content between blogs is a fool's errand. Any outbound links will not be in the feed.

Connecting to the other blog's database also proved impossible.

I ended up just scraping the content from the other site with curl + simple_xml and echoing it into the other page.